# I How to correctly convert date in scraping application?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a such code:

```
def _updated_external(self):
   return dig(self.property_data, 'analyticsInfo', 'analyticsProperty', 'added')
```

And it returns me `"20201104"` I need to make YYYY-MM-DD

Function `dig` works with nested dicts.

I need to get date and convert it for another function.

I know that better to use `dateparser.parser` but little bit confused about how to write it in correct way.

Comment: what do you have in `dig`? What do you expect without code?

Comment: If you have string `20201104` then split it using `[:4]`, `[4:6]`, `[6:]` and add dots.

Comment: @barny you added `YYYY-MM-DD` but OP didn't mentioned what format it uses. What if OP needs `YYYY-DD-MM` or `DD.MM.YYYY` or other format ?  :)

Comment: @furas No that was OP editing. I changed scrapping in the title to scraping as scrapping means discarding as rubbish, whereas scraping means collection of contents of a web page.

Comment: @barry sorry - when I checked edition history I saw both changes and I thought both are your changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have date as string then you can use standard string function to change it

```
txt = '20201104'
result = txt[:4] + '-' + txt[4:6] + '-' + txt[6:]
```

Result:

```
'2020-11-04'
```

---

Eventaully you can use standard `datetime` to parse it

```
txt = '20201104'
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(txt, '%Y%m%d')
```

Result:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 0, 0)
```

And later you can use `strftime` to generate in other format.

```
result.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Result:

```
'2020-11-04'
```